# Method for proving polynomial inequalities

Tags: inequality, polynomials

> Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that
>   $\text{(a) }x^{10}-x^7+x^4-x^2+1>0\\
> \text{(b) }x^4-x^2-3x+5>0$

Possibly it can be proved in a few different ways, but I have first tried to prove it reducing to a sum of squares. After too many attempts and using a trial-and-error method, I got
$$x^4\left({x^3-\frac12}\right)^2+\left({\frac12x^2-1}\right)^2+\frac12x^4>0$$
for $\text{(a)}$. My question is: is there any easier method to prove this for any polinomial which is always positive? Also, I am wondering if there is any other simplier method than reducing to sum of squares.

Comment: If you've been taught differentiation, try and use that.

Comment: Did you try taking derivatives and show they are positive?

Comment: Of corse, I tried using derivatives, but I want method to prove any polynomial. If I have, for example, polynomial of degree $12$ and I take derivative, I again must prove it for polynomial of degree $11$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We look only at $P(x)=x^{10}-x^7+x^4-x^2+1$. It is clear at a glance that $P(x)\gt 0$ if $|x|\ge 1$. Grouping as $(x^{10}-x^7)+(x^4-x^2)+1$ does it.

So we look at $|x|\lt 1$. Negative $x$ in this range are easy to deal with, so we concentrate on $0\lt x\lt 1$. Since $x^4-x^7\gt 0$, we have $P(x)\gt 1-x^2\gt 0$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But, your solution doesn't answer my question. I am searching for the general method to prove this  for any polynomial inequality. For example, how to prove that $x^{16}-3x^{15}+7x^{14}-4x^{13}-2x^{12}-7x^{11}+9x^{10}-8x^9+21x^8+7x^7+3x^6-17x^5+4x^3-x^2-x+1>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I was not attempting to answer the general question, except for in a highly indirect way advocating a "problem solving" approach in which we *look* at specific features of our object. From a logician's point of view, by a result of Tarski there is an algorithm for deciding whether a first order sentence in the usual language of ring theory is true in the reals.

Comment: There is a fair bit of literature on efficient algorithms for deciding on positive definiteness, and semidefiniteness, for polynomials in $n$ variables. The old stuff in one variable was based on Sturm sequences.

Comment: This is not exactlly what I want, but thank you anyway.

Comment: You are welcome. Should really not accept yet, it diminishes the chance of getting a "real" solution. A Google search will get you algorithms. But maybe someone will save you the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an easy method to do by hand,  but one that always works is to use [Sturm's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) to find the number of real roots of the polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way for $(a)$ is using the AM-GMs:
$$\frac12x^{10}+\frac12x^4 \ge x^7, \quad \frac12x^4+\frac12 \ge x^2$$
$$\implies x^{10}-x^7+x^4-x^2+1 \ge \frac12+\frac12x^{10}>0$$

and similarly for $(b)$:
$$\frac12x^4+\frac12 \ge x^2, \quad \frac12x^4+\frac32+\frac32+\frac32 \ge 2\times 3^{3/4}x> 3x$$

Not always applicable, of course.

Also you may want to know that for univariate polynomials theoretically you can always express as a sum of squares, and while tedious, somehow the end result is more satisfying...